# C# : there is already an open DataReader associated with this command

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, sqldatareader

I currently have a problem with multiple `SqlDataReader` and commands in a single method. This method should delete a customer + its related address, networks, ipaddresses...

When I execute the code, I get an error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

So I googled a little bit and read, that the

```
using(SqlDataReader....)
```

and adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to the connection string should help.

I'm using SQL Server 2014, I heard that there is a problem with SQL Server 2005, so that shouldnt be a problem..

But it still doesn't work...

The exception is thrown at

```
var addressId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Connection string:

```
Data Source=.\\DATABASE;Initial Catalog=customer;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxxx!
```

Code:

```
public static Boolean ExecuteDeleteCutomer(string customerId) {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(new DatabaseConnection().ConnectionString)) {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;
        SqlDataReader locationReader;
        SqlDataReader networkReader;
        SqlDataReader ipaddressReader;

        // Start a local transaction to delete a customer and related table entries.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("StartTransaction DeleteCustomer");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try {
            //First get the locations of selected customer
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", customerId);
            command.CommandText =
                    "SELECT l_id from location where c_id = @customerId";
            locationReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            using (locationReader) { //save location ids in a reader
                while (locationReader.Read()) {
                    var locationID = locationReader.NextResult();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationId", locationID);
                    command.CommandText =
                        "SELECT a_id from address where l_location = @locationId";
                    var addressId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar(); // get address ID to delete later

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressId", addressId);
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT n_id from network where n_location = @locationId";

                    using (networkReader = command.ExecuteReader()) { // save networks in a reader;
                        while (networkReader.Read()) {
                            var networkId = networkReader.NextResult();
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@networkId", networkId);
                            command.CommandText = "SELECT ip_id from ipaddress where n_id = @networkId";

                            using (ipaddressReader = command.ExecuteReader()) { // get ipaddressId ID to delete later
                                while (ipaddressReader.Read()) {
                                    var ipaddressId = ipaddressReader.NextResult();
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ipId", ipaddressId);
                                    command.CommandText = "Delete from ipaddress where ip_id = @ipId; ";
                                    command.ExecuteScalar();
                                }
                            }

                            command.CommandText = "Delete from network where n_id = @networkId; ";
                            command.ExecuteScalar();
                        }
                    }

                    command.CommandText = "Delete from location where l_id = @locationID; ";
                    command.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }

            command.CommandText = "Delete from customer where c_id = @customerId; ";
            command.ExecuteScalar();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();

            return true;
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            try {
                transaction.Rollback();
            } 
            catch (Exception ex2) {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error-message is self-explanatory!

Comment: Why `var locationID = locationReader.NextResult();`? If you have a query with multiple select statements this advances the reader to the next result. I doubt that you want to do that in the `while (networkReader.Read())` loop. Instead you want to use `int networkId = networkReader.GetInt32(0);`

Comment: You can't have more than one open DataReader against a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message reads, you already have an open `DataReader` associated with that `Command` object.

You need to create a new `SqlCommand` object for each (nested) command that you want to execute.

```
SqlCommand locationCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
SqlCommand networkCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
SqlCommand ipAddrCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
```

Assign your `CommandText` as needed to each of those command objects, then you can call `ExecuteReader` on each one and process as needed.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I created a single Command for each nested command :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a different command instance for the outer and inner commands; so essentially:

```
var innerCommand = ...
innerCommand.CommandText = "Delete from ipaddress where ip_id = @ipId; ";
var ipId = innerCommand.Parameters.Add(...);
while (ipaddressReader.Read()) {
    ipId.Value = ...
    innerCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

(and similar for each command)

Basically, each command instance should only be executing once at a time, regardless of whether they share a connection or not.